# sound canceling when another one starts playing unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

basicly i mostly copied code from tutorial but i have problem with sounds canceling after another sound plays. for example when i shoot and play sound if i hit enemy and explosion sound plays shooting sound gets muted.
i already have this script on empty gameobject soundmanager and access it through soundmanager.instance.playSingle(sound).
i dont know what else to do to make sounds not cancel each other!
any help is appreciated

```
void Awake()
{
    //Check if there is already an instance of SoundManager
    if (instance == null)
        //if not, set it to this.
        instance = this;
    //If instance already exists:
    else if (instance != this)
        //Destroy this, this enforces our singleton pattern so there can only be one instance of SoundManager.
        Destroy(gameObject);

    //Set SoundManager to DontDestroyOnLoad so that it won't be destroyed when reloading our scene.
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}


//Used to play single sound clips.
public void PlaySingle(AudioClip clip)
{
    //Set the clip of our efxSource audio source to the clip passed in as a parameter.
    efxSource.clip = clip;

    //Play the clip.
    efxSource.PlayOneShot(efxSource.clip);
}
public void PlayCrash(AudioClip clip)
{
    //Set the clip of our efxSource audio source to the clip passed in as a parameter.
    crashSource.clip = clip;

    //Play the clip.
    crashSource.PlayOneShot(crashSource.clip);
}

public void PlayShoot(AudioClip clip)
{
    //Set the clip of our efxSource audio source to the clip passed in as a parameter.
    ShootSource.clip = clip;

    //Play the clip.
    // ShootSource.PlayOneShot();
    ShootSource.PlayOneShot(ShootSource.clip);
}

//RandomizeSfx chooses randomly between various audio clips and slightly changes their pitch.
public void RandomizeSfx(params AudioClip[] clips)
{
    //Generate a random number between 0 and the length of our array of clips passed in.
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, clips.Length);

    //Choose a random pitch to play back our clip at between our high and low pitch ranges.
    float randomPitch = Random.Range(lowPitchRange, highPitchRange);

    //Set the pitch of the audio source to the randomly chosen pitch.
    efxSource.pitch = randomPitch;

    //Set the clip to the clip at our randomly chosen index.
    efxSource.clip = clips[randomIndex];

    //Play the clip.
    efxSource.Play();
}
```

}

Comment: Without wanting to get dragged in too far, why not add another audio souce for the second sound.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either create a seperate audiosource that handles the explosions (maybe on a projectile object/ class), or if you don't need anything fancy, you could use  `AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint()`. [See docs.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint.html)

So to put it into action, you would modify your `PlayCrash` method to accept the position where to play the crash (or if it doesn't matter, just use `Vector3.Zero`

```
public void PlayCrash(AudioClip clip, Vector3 location)
{
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(clip, location);
}
```